# Unable to set range when using XPath with predicate /closed/

Tags: xml, vba, xpath, excel-2003

Closed the question as it wasn't an error - it just isn't possible

I am trying to return a range that contains all elements in a listobject/xmlmap where a sibling element meets some criteria (a particular elements values are not empty/blank/zero-length).

If I try to return the entire element of the xmlmap, I get the range returned correctly. However as soon as I add any criteria, the range object isn't set and I get an error.

I have removed the namespace refrences throughout, to try and pin down the error, but even without namespace declarations, the error remains. The code below is a much simplified version of what I'm working with, to show the error.

XML data

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ROOT>
  <RECORD>
    <ITEMA/>
    <ITEMB>RED</ITEMB>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ITEMA>A</ITEMA>
    <ITEMB>BLUE</ITEMB>
  </RECORD>
  <RECORD>
    <ITEMA>B</ITEMA>
    <ITEMB>GREEN</ITEMB>
  </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

XSD used to set up XmlMap in Excel

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="ROOT" type="RootType"/>
<xs:complexType name="RootType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="RECORD" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ITEMA"/>
                    <xs:element name="ITEMB"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Working VBA Code (without predicate)

```
Sub TestSUCCESS()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim sSourceXPath As String

sSourceXPath = "/ROOT/RECORD/ITEMB"

Set rngSource = Sheet4.XmlDataQuery(sSourceXPath)
Debug.Print rngSource.Address

End Sub
```

Non-Working VBA Code (with predicate)

```
Sub TestERROR()

Dim rngSource As Range
Dim sSourceXPath As String

sSourceXPath = "/ROOT/RECORD/ITEMA[text()[normalize-space()]]"

Set rngSource = Sheet4.XmlDataQuery(sSourceXPath)
If Not rngSource Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rngSource.Address
Else
    Debug.Print "ERROR: rngSource isn't set"        
End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried using the following xpath:

```
"/ROOT/RECORD/ITEMB[../ITEMA[string-length(text()) > 0]]"
```

As well as variations of the folloving just to get anything to work, but to no avail:

```
sSourceXPath = "/ROOT/RECORD/ITEMB[../ITEMA[.="A"]]"
```

All the xPath examples I've given work in Altova XMLSpy 2005.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to where I've gone wrong ?

Comment: I do not think closing this question was the appropriate action. Perhaps user user might have the sane problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the xpaht point of view your attempts are ok. But I would prefer for example to select ITEMB with TIMEA is not empty.

```
"/ROOT/RECORD/ITEMB[normalize-space(../ITEMA)]"
```

**But this all will not work with Worksheet.XmlDataQuery**

Because of (my best guess): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839982.aspx

*The XmlDataQuery method allows you to query for the existence of particular map data. It can not be used to query for a piece of data in a map. For example, it is valid for a mapped range to exist in which the XPath for that range is "/root/People[@Age="23"]/FirstName". An XmlDataQuery query for this XPath location path will returnreturns the correct range. However, a query for "/root/People[FirstName="Joe"]" hoping to find "Joe" within the above mapped range will fail because the XPath definitions for the mapped ranges are different.*

Comment: How would you suggest I proceed? Would you load the xml from the xmlmap into a MSXML6.0 DOM and xpath/query the elements using that instead? Or will that lead to the same wall?

Comment: I suspect MSXML6.0 DOM  will do. But I'm not sure this will help you because I do not now which functions of Worksheet you will missing than. Therefore I think you shut iterate to the rngSource.

Comment: Please replace "suspect" to "expect" in my previous comment. `:-(